# converting keras in python to java

Tags: java, python, neural-network, keras

I currently have a working neural network in python using keras, however, I need the final product to be in java. My research so far has not shown a direct translation between python and java for keras, but is there a way to save the model using keras in python, and then much as we load the model in another file in python, load the model in java? Or in other words, what is the simplest way to convert my keras neural network into a form that is compatible with java?

Answer (score 3):

[DeepLearning4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/) can be used to load keras models.

If you have both json file and .h5(weights) file you can use `KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights` class to load the model as follows.

```
MultiLayerNetwork network = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights("PATH TO YOUR JSON FILE","PATH TO YOUR H5 FILE")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer weights & architecture with H5 file format. Keras recommend h5.

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [Deep Java Library (DJL)](https://djl.ai) to load Keras model in Java and run inference. DJL is an open source Deep Learning Library for Java. Checkout the github repo: https://github.com/awslabs/djl

There is a blogpost: https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-pneumonia-from-chest-x-ray-images-e02bcf705dd6

And the demo project can be found: https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/blob/master/pneumonia-detection/README.md